# missing files when extracting tarball in golang

Tags: ubuntu, go, gzip, tar

I'm trying out this function to just untar a file after I've ungzip'd it, however, when it untars there are some folders missing and I can't figure out why. UnGzip works fine when I open the created tarfile via GUI so that function isnt included.

```
func main() {
fileUrl := "https://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.103.1.tar.gz"
filePath := "clamav-0.103.1.tar.gz"
tempFolder := "temp"
    
err := os.Mkdir(tempFolder, 0755)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

err = DownloadFile(filePath, fileUrl)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("Downloaded: " + fileUrl)

UnGzip(filePath,tempFolder + "/clamav.tar")
UnTar(tempFolder + "/clamav.tar",tempFolder + "/clamAV/")
//err := os.RemoveAll("tempFolder")
//if err != nil {
    //panic(err)
//}
```

}

```
func UnTar(tarball, target string) error {
reader, err := os.Open(tarball)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer reader.Close()
tarReader := tar.NewReader(reader)

for {
    header, err := tarReader.Next()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    path := filepath.Join(target, header.Name)
    info := header.FileInfo()
    if info.IsDir() {
        if err = os.MkdirAll(path, info.Mode()); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        continue
    }

    file, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_WRONLY, info.Mode())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    _, err = io.Copy(file, tarReader)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
return nil
```

}

here's what I should get:[want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abrYZ.png)
and here's what I have: [have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSFm9.png)

Comment: Archive directories are not always listed separately from the files. Are you getting an error when attempting to create a file in a non-existent directory?

Comment: @jimB No errors and I'm positive the directory exists

Comment: I don't understand, you said the some folders/directories are missing -- but you're positive they exist?

Comment: my bad I thought you meant the parent directory, shouldn't the folders be created using mkdirAll? (I updated the question to include pictures of the files im getting vs the files I need) I would thing if it were a problem with files trying to be installed in non-existing folders, it wouldnt create ANY folders as opposed to getting just a few folders, plus I'm still not getting some of the files that aren't even in a directory within the parent

Comment: This tarball seems to have all the directories listed separately, though that's something you should look out for. You're not checking the error returned from `UnTar`, which is going to tell you what is going wrong here. Always check your errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running into `ulimit` for the allowed number of open files per process. Run `ulimit` with the `-a` flag, and I think the default `open files` limit is 1024. The tarball has 2758 files.

This is because you defer the closing of the file descriptor in the for loop processing the `tarReader`.

To fix it, close each file as you've dealt with them:

```golang
func UnTar(tarball, target string) error {
    reader, err := os.Open(tarball)
    if err != nil {
        return err 
    }   
    defer reader.Close()
    tarReader := tar.NewReader(reader)

    for {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err 
        }

        path := filepath.Join(target, header.Name)
        info := header.FileInfo()
        if info.IsDir() {
            if err = os.MkdirAll(path, info.Mode()); err != nil {
                return err 
            }
            continue
        }

        err = processOneFile(tarReader, path, info.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err 
        }
    }   
    return nil 
}

func processOneFile(tarReader io.Reader, filePath string, fileMode os.FileMode) error {
    file, err := os.OpenFile(filePath, os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_WRONLY, fileMode)
    if err != nil {
        return err 
    }   
    defer file.Close() // close error discarded
    _, err = io.Copy(file, tarReader)
    return err 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some example code:

```
package main

import (
   "archive/tar"
   "compress/gzip"
   "io"
   "os"
   "path"
)

func extract(source string) error {
   file, err := os.Open(source)
   if err != nil { return err }
   defer file.Close()
   gzRead, err := gzip.NewReader(file)
   if err != nil { return err }
   defer gzRead.Close()
   tarRead := tar.NewReader(gzRead)
   for {
      cur, err := tarRead.Next()
      if err == io.EOF { break } else if err != nil { return err }
      os.MkdirAll(path.Dir(cur.Name), os.ModeDir)
      switch cur.Typeflag {
      case tar.TypeReg:
         create, err := os.Create(cur.Name)
         if err != nil { return err }
         defer create.Close()
         create.ReadFrom(tarRead)
      case tar.TypeLink:
         os.Link(cur.Linkname, cur.Name)
      }
   }
   return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
package main

func main() {
   extract("clamav-0.103.1.tar.gz")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer about the `ulimit` is already really good, there are two things I just want to add:

1. you can decompress gzip and read the tar file at the same time instead of creating a temp file in between. You could also directly stream the file from the URL and extract it while downloading
2. Someone could probably create a malicious tar.gz file that would make your code overwrite important files using something like [zipslip](https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability) (especially if your program runs as root, someone could inject a file path like `../../../../etc/passwd` and thus overwrite that file, maybe even edit the crontab file and execute code that way?), you should probably check for that

With that in mind, we can write a function that directly extracts from an `io.Reader` that also checks for any paths outside of the target directory:

```
// untargz decompresses a gzipped tar stream to the directory specified by target.
// Note that `file` should be closed by the caller
func untargz(file io.Reader, targetDir string) (err error) {
    gz, err := gzip.NewReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    // This does not close file
    defer gz.Close()

    tarReader := tar.NewReader(gz)

    for {
        header, err := tarReader.Next()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // This can be dangerous, similar to zipslip
        path := filepath.Join(targetDir, header.Name)

        // Check for ZipSlip. More Info: https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability#go
        if !strings.HasPrefix(path, filepath.Clean(targetDir)+string(os.PathSeparator)) {
            err = fmt.Errorf("%s: illegal file path", path)
            return err
        }

        info := header.FileInfo()
        if info.IsDir() {
            if err = os.MkdirAll(path, info.Mode()); err != nil {
                return err
            }
            continue
        }

        file, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC|os.O_WRONLY, info.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(file, tarReader)
        if err != nil {
            file.Close()
            return err
        }

        err = file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

It might also be beneficial to think about what would happen if a directory is declared after a file that is in that directory (because then `os.Create` fails), but this function doesn't handle that case.

This function could be used to directly stream to an output directory, but I'm honestly not sure if that is what you want:

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get(`https://www.clamav.net/downloads/production/clamav-0.103.1.tar.gz`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    err = untargz(bufio.NewReader(resp.Body), "out")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println("Done")
}
```

You can find the full file [here](https://play.golang.org/p/5ejGY89LMRM).